# Axios (or node) gets stuck if the petitions fails

Tags: node.js, http, get, axios

I have the following code:

```
import axios from "axios";

export async function get(url: string, n: number = 10) {
  let error;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    try {
      console.log("This get executed");
      await axios({ method: "get", url: url, responseType: "document" });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("This code does not");
      error = err;
    }
  }
  throw error;
}

get("https://manganeo.com/")
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

What I am trying to do is repeat the petition until its success. If you call `get` with an existing url it works well. Nonetheless, if the url returns a 404 error, this function gets hanged.

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems [Axios does not come with a default timeout set](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/defaults.js#L67-L71), so I'm gonna guess your request never gets timed out and it hangs indefinitely.

Try again with a timeout and see if that fixes it:

```js
await axios({ method: "get", url: url, timeout: 10000, responseType: "document" });
```